# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'stocks' before initialization

Tags: javascript, module

I'm trying to import an object into another JS file, and I keep getting this error, Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'stocks' before initialization. I've declared stocks, and I've imported it correctly, so I can't see what I did wrong. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

In the stocks file:

```
export const stocks = {
    megaCorp: {
        name: 'Mega Corporation',
        value: decideStockValue(),
        portIn: 0,
        document: "mega"
    },

    lunaBake: {
        name: "Luna Baking",
        value: decideStockValue(),
        portIn: 1,
        document: "luna"
    },
}
```

And in the user file :

```
import { stocks } from "./stocks.js";

export let user = {
    money: 2000,
    portfolio: [0, 0, 0, 0]
}

function getValue () {
    let value = user.money;
    let cannon = stocks.cannonRock.value * user.portfolio[0];
    let alpha = stocks.alphaComp.value * user.portfolio[1];
    let luna = stocks.lunaBake.value * user.portfolio[2];
    let mega = stocks.megaCorp.value * user.portfolio[3];
    value += cannon;
    value += alpha;
    value += luna;
    value += mega;
    return value;   
}

user.value = getValue();
```

Comment: The code u have shared is syntactically fine, you are probabbly getting the error from more than just that code u shared

Comment: I commented out all the lines that had a 'stocks' call in user.js, and it worked fine

Comment: thats interesting , where are u running the code?

Comment: like what environment

Comment: localhost server on Chrome browser

Comment: Can you verify that you are importing stocks correctly? What do you get when you `console.log(stocks)` right after the import? Also, where is cannonRock and alphaComp in your stocks object?

Comment: what bundler are u using? webpack, parcel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging for a little, I closed the server and opened it again. This time, it worked fine. I'm still not sure why the original error happened, but now it's working great. Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 5):

Again Looking at the code it seems syntactically fine, so this is not an answer but i rather want to share a snippet of code to see how it behaves.

The error you shared   `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'variable_name' before initialization` is thrown when a lexical variable was accessed before it was initialized ( what is known as a temporal dead zone error), however in the code you share there is nothing that should throw this error.

for example this code will throw this error

```
const x = 3
function a(){
    console.log(x)
    const x = 5;
}
a()
```

Assuming indeed that the error originated from the user file, then the following code might solve it. In the code u had getValue was a function expression that should be hoisted ( which again should be fine), but it could be that a bundler you are using is misbehaving.

```
import { stocks } from "./stocks.js";

const getValue = (stocks, money, portfolio) => {
  let value = money;
  let cannon = stocks.cannonRock.value * portfolio[0];
  let alpha = stocks.alphaComp.value * portfolio[1];
  let luna = stocks.lunaBake.value * portfolio[2];
  let mega = stocks.megaCorp.value * portfolio[3];
  value += cannon;
  value += alpha;
  value += luna;
  value += mega;
  return value;
};

const money = 2000;
const portfolio = [0, 0, 0, 0];
export const user = {
  money,
  portfolio,
  value: getValue(stocks, money, portfolio),
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'process' before initialization`

when I attempted to do this:

```
require("dotenv-safe").config();
console.log(process.env);

const DATABASE_URI = process.env.DATABASE_URI;
```

Turns out, the problem was I was mistakenly declaring process further down in the same file like this:

```
const process = require("process");
```

This require was unnecessary since it's available in Node's global context. Deleting that line fixed the problem.

Comment: 'require' is not part of standard Javascript and should not be used. Use 'import' instead it.

Comment: require belongs to CommonJS modules which are standard in all versions of Node. import is the ES module syntax introduced in Node 13.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a classic example of cycle overloading of certain dependancy (c) Sergei Vohmianin

The easiest thing you can do is to move that object into it's separate module just to omit cycle like app => method => app.